# how to get a job's result of gitlab ci stage

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab ci pipeline like below, and there is a bash script `notify.sh` which will send different notification depends on stage `build` result(success or failed), currently I use a arg `--result` to control the logic, and I write two jobs for stage `notify`(success-notify and failed-notify) and assign the value of `--result` manually. Is there a way to get the stage `build` result directly(like STAGE_BUILD_STATE) instead of use statement `when`?

```
---
stages:
- build
- notify

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - build something

success-notify:
  stage: notify
  script:
  - bash notify.sh --result success

failed-notify:
  stage: notify
  script:
  - bash notify.sh --result failed
  when: on_failure
```